# JSP show button if session is active

Tags: jsp

I want to show different buttons depending on whether the session is active, however I am receiving errors when run.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
<%if (session == null)
{
<INPUT TYPE="button" onClick="parent.location='CustomerLogin.jsp'" value="Customer Login">

<INPUT TYPE="button" onClick="parent.location='ManagerLogin.jsp'" value="Manager Login">

}
else
{

<INPUT TYPE="button" onClick="parent.location='Logout.jsp'" value="Logout">             
}%>
```

I get an error for every part of both buttons, e.g INPUT cannot be resolved to a variable, onClick cannot be resolved etc.

I am trying to show different HTML buttons depending on the session.

Thanks.

Comment: Please say what are exactly the error messages, and what happens. Without that, your question is likely to be closed as unclear or off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you need to keep your HTML outside the *scriptlet* `<% %>` blocks.

```
<% if (session == null) { %>

    <INPUT TYPE="button" onClick="parent.location='CustomerLogin.jsp'"
           value="Customer Login">
    <INPUT TYPE="button" onClick="parent.location='ManagerLogin.jsp'"
           value="Manager Login">

<% } else { %>

    <INPUT TYPE="button" onClick="parent.location='Logout.jsp'"
           value="Logout">             

<% } %>
```

A *scriptlet* in a JSP only encapsulates valid Java code. But, the conditional blocks defined by two or more *scriptlets* apply to the HTML content that (although not enclosed but) falls between them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes because you have put the HTML tags inside JSP Scriptlets, HTML tags should be out side of Scriptlets, I strongly recommend not to use Scriptlets which violates the design principles.

Syntactically below is correct :

```
<%if (session == null){%>
<INPUT TYPE="button" onClick="parent.location='CustomerLogin.jsp'" value="Customer Login">

<INPUT TYPE="button" onClick="parent.location='ManagerLogin.jsp'" value="Manager Login">
<%
}
else
{
%>
<INPUT TYPE="button" onClick="parent.location='Logout.jsp'" value="Logout">             
<%}%>
```